# How i play video in swift Using AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer, phpicker

Am using PHPicker to get videos in my photos library Photos.
Getting Video from PHPicker

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
    results.forEach { result in
        if result.itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.movie.identifier) {
            result.itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier, options: [:]) { videoUrl, phpError in
                if let url = videoUrl as? URL {
                    // Here is Video URL
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my video player code

```
func playVideo(url: URL) {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerVC.player = player
    playerVC.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
    playerVC.player?.play()
    self.present(playerVC, animated: true)
}
```

when i select and play a video  am getting this

[image: VIdeo player image]

Comment: Not sure it will work or not but  Try                 `url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` Or copy that file somewhere in document dir and play from there

Also I notice you are looping the result, just grab one and try